# Json files delete themselves after edit launching minecraft

Tags: json, minecraft

my .json file deletes itself after edit when I launch Minecraft I used notepad++ to save the new edit. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: still looking for awnser here guys any advice would help--thanks:)

Comment: When you don't have reply, I suggest you to "bump" your question by editing it. Specially add details ... Here, we don't have so much details. Which file ? Where ?